# Was it Daniel who did not understand the vision in Daniel 8:27?

Tags: referent-identification, prophecy, daniel, eschatology, messiah

After narrating some visions to Daniel (Daniel 8:1-25) at the end its not clear who did not understand what had just been narrated

Daniel 8:27 NKJV

> 27 And I, Daniel, fainted and was sick for days; afterward I arose and went about the king’s  business. I was astonished by the vision, but no one understood it.

Was it Daniel who did not understand the meaning of the vision or was it the people around him?

Comment: The Hebrew is *'en mevin*: "there was no discerning". Sounds like himself as much as everyone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Luke Sawczak said, the Hebrew phrase there implies no one understood it -
including Daniel himself.

YLT says:

> ...
>
> And I, Daniel, have been, yea, I became sick for days, and I rise, and do the king's work, and am astonished at the appearance, and there is none understanding.

Daniel recorded a similar situation in chapter 12.

Daniel 12:8-9:

> ...
>
> And I have heard, and I do not understand, and I say, 'O my lord, what is the latter end of these?'
>
> And he saith, 'Go, Daniel; for hidden and sealed are the things till the time of the end;
>
> ...

He says that he did not understand the vision and that was by design. Daniel is not talking about chapter 8 in chapter 12, but the fact he says he himself did not understand in chapter 12 leads me to think he meant he himself did not understand in chapter 8. If he understood the vision he could have just explained it to others like he explained the metal statue in Daniel 2.